# React Router Redirect not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, routes, router

Hei Guys,

I got a strange problem that is stopping my development progress for days now.

In my React App I'm using React-Router (Browser Router).
Everthing is working fine (Link, Route, Switch) except Redirect.

redirect is changing the URL but not Rendering the 'new' component. E.g. I got a login screen and after Submit I want to redirect to user screen. Url is changing to URL but screen stays empty (The Sidenav is rendered but not the component, that shows the users information).

Does anybody know how to solve this? There are no errors in console.

Body Component:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Home />
  </Route>
  <PrivateRoute path="/user" component = {User} />
  <Route path="/login">
    <Login/>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/register">
    <Register />
  </Route>
  <NotFound />
</Switch>
```

Private Route:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, user, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={
        props => {
          if (user) {
            return <Component {...rest} {...props} />
          } else {
            return <Redirect to={
              {
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }
            } />
          }
        }
      } />
    )
  }
  
  export default PrivateRoute;
```

Return Value of the render method of Login Screen, this part should be rendered when logged in:

```
return (    
              <Route render={
                props => {
                    return <Redirect to={
                      {
                        pathname: '/user',
                        state: {
                          from: this.props.location
                        }
                      }
                    } />
                  }
                }
               />
          );
```

On Reloading everthing workls perfectly.
Using of Private Route also works.

No Typos.

regards

Manuel

Comment: Post some code please :)

Comment: you are redirecting to an unmapped url maybe? a typo somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You should not return a Route at your render method but rather a Redirect directly.

so sth like

```
return (
<>
{isLoggedIn ? 
<Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/user',
                state: { from: this.props.location }
             }} />
: LOGIN_FORM_HTML
}
</>
)
```

Comment: I did try That But that did. Not work either

Comment: have similar piece of code in my application and it does work. can't think of sth else to be honest. maybe a small codesandbox if possible could help us work on it and find a fix.

Comment: to be honest I switched to Angular now because it offers much more functionality for Requests and that's what I need a lot